# java replacing \\r\\n and putting them in array

Tags: java

i tried all example here but none of them worked in the below case , i want to replace "\n\r" and prepare an array like below .

i tried running as below but it is not showing me the expected result

```
String m = "\\r\\nDate cf Mfg. \\r\\nMRP \\r\\n(Incl.of ali taxes) \\r\\nI I i I I I I I I I I I I I ! I I I Ill I I I I Ill \\r\\nS.No:602NRJT053740 \\r\\n61281660 \\r\\nModel .•GL-B171RDCM \\r\\n: ADGZEBNON) \\r\\nRefrigerator ";
String ar[] = m.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "#").split("#");
System.out.println(ar.length);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your string literal: you double-escaped `\r` and `\n`, so they are not actually `\r` and `\n`, they are pairs of backslash plus `r` and backslash plus `n`.

Double backslashes are needed in the regex, because its content is un-escaped twice - once by Java compiler, and once more by the regex engine. String literals, on the other hand, need single escaping.

To fix this problem, remove double backslashes from the string literal initializing `m`:

```
String m = "\r\nDate cf Mfg. \r\nMRP \r\n(Incl.of ali taxes) \r\nI I i I I I I I I I I I I I ! I I I Ill I I I I Ill \r\nS.No:602NRJT053740 \r\n61281660 \r\nModel .•GL-B171RDCM \r\n: ADGZEBNON) \r\nRefrigerator ";
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/tNTghd) (prints 10).

Comment: but this is what i am getting ..is there any other way round

Comment: @HimanshuKhandelwal What do you mean by "this is what you are getting"? Are you getting it from a file, and it has literally `\r\n` *text* in it?

Comment: @HimanshuKhandelwal If you need to match text with actual backslashes and so on, you need to quadruple-escape your slashes - i.e. `m.replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\n", "#").split("#");` ([demo](http://ideone.com/5xKTn3))

Comment: thanks very much , it worked ..dont know where to tick or accept this answer